# How to profile use of Viewstate by controls

Tags: asp.net, profiling, viewstate

I have a couple of pages that are bulky due to the viewstate. I have following question:

- is there any tool that can track viewstate of individual control on page and tell me which control is taking maxm viewstate
- also can i know which controls viewstate is not being used and disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Viewstate Utilities listed here http://blogs.msdn.com/rextang/archive/2007/05/25/2868250.aspx. I always store Viewstate in the database rather than send it back and forth over the internet. Example Code here http://www.componentworkshop.com/blog/2009/06/27/advanced-net-storing-viewstate-in-a-database

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on trace on the page and that should show how much viewstate is used for each control.

I have no good answer to your second question, but one rule of thumb I use when i develop webforms is that i set EnableViewState=false immediately after I've created an Ascx.

That way I can turn it on when I actually need it and not wonder if my databound controls uses alot of viewstate.